# Can I make a template specialisation that inherits from its base?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

In other words: Is it possible to make a template specialisation that inherits from its base, like this:

```
template <class T>  
class A{};  
template <>  
class A<int>:public A<>{};
```

so that A has all of A's functions?
I'm new here, so I dunno how to format, just in case the code comes up incorrectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can, with a bit of trickery. This pattern is sometimes called **“template subclassing”** and is used extensively in the [SeqAn](http://www.seqan.de) library.

The trick is to give the base class an additional template argument tag which determines the type identity:

```
template <typename T, typename Spec = void>
struct A { … };

// inheritance tag:
struct Derived { };

template <typename T>
struct A<T, Derived> : public A<T, void> { … };
```

Here, `void` denotes the base (you could also use a dedicated tag `Base` but `void` works fine) and `Derived`, an empty struct, denotes the derived class.

Now you can instantiate and use the templates as follows:

```
A<int> the_base;
A<int, Derived> the_derived;

the_base.do_something();
the_derived.do_something();
```

For a real-world example, consider the [`String`](http://docs.seqan.de/seqan/dev2/?i=Class.String) class from SeqAn:

```
String<Dna> some_dna = "GATTACA";
String<Dna, Packed> more_dna = "GATTACA";
```

The second type derived from the first one, but is a specialisation which *packs* its characters as tightly as possible (for DNA, this means putting four DNA characters in each byte).

Comment: @HighCommander I appreciate edits with corrections in general but next time it would be nice if you could wait a bit after the original submission in case the original author is still editing his own post (as was the case here).